# Azure / Cosmos DB is counting requests (RUs) I didn't make

Tags: .net, azure, monitoring, azure-cosmosdb

I'm working on a simple Xamarin app, that needs to connect to and validate login information against a Cosmos DB collection of users.

My app has had two requests, but the activity in Azure portal is showing many more. Also I only did an "insert" into the azure portal for a single document to test the connection and some basic functionality

What is going on here?

I created the database around 11:00 and this was captured 12:15:

[image: Capture from overview]
Code that is establishing the connection:

```
public void Start(string ConnectionString = @"mongodb://secrets"){
//ConnectionString = @"mongodb://192.168.0.111:27017"; // Local test mongodb

MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.FromUrl(new MongoUrl(ConnectionString));

settings.SslSettings = new SslSettings() { EnabledSslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12 };

//var mongoClient = new MongoClient(settings);

CosmosClient = new MongoClient(settings);
CosmosDatabase = CosmosClient.GetDatabase("dbname");
CosmosUsersCollection = CosmosDatabase.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("users");
Ready = true;}
```

Code for checking login:

```
public async Task<string> LoginAsync(string name, string password){
if (!Ready) { Start(); }
var builder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
var filter = builder.Eq("nick", name) & builder.Eq("password", password);

string output;

try
{
    var var1 = await CosmosUsersCollection.Find(filter).FirstAsync();

    Console.WriteLine("LOGIN RESPONSE: " + var1);

    output = var1.ToJson();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("LOGIN FAILED: " + ex.Message);
    output = ex.Message;
    throw;
}

return output;}
```

And the data I'm reading from

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId(""),
"nick" : "FRANK_1988",
"password" : "password",
"location" : {
    "type" : "Point",
    "coordinates" : [ 
        58.2237183172273, 
        7.98107150169605
    ]
}
```

Comment: While you haven't shown any code, your graph shows barely any RU consumed. Perhaps edit your question to show the code you're executing, and the data you're saving, which is hitting Cosmos DB. This could be, for example, index creation (the "other" activity in the chart).

Comment: @DavidMakogon Now I've edited. I realize I should've added code and data from the start, (just an oversight).I'm not saving data, I'm doing a single connect and read from the db

Comment: If you go to **Azure Monitor** in the Azure Portal, you can see where those "Other" metrics are coming from. In a Mongo account, there are several commands that are grouped in that metric and they are displayed in detail when you review the data in Azure Monitor.

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta Could you be more specific, as I'm unable to find the details you are refering to. I just started working with Azure, and I see I'll have to sign up for a course in the near future to wrap my head around this massive beast of a platform

Comment: @FrankR.Haugen Added details as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand the detail of those requests, you can use **Azure Monitor**. Go to the Azure Portal and look for the Monitor service:

[image: Azure Monitor service]

Go to **Metrics**:

[image: Metrics menu item]

Then find your resource by Subscription, Resource Group and name and select the **Mongo Requests** metric:

[image: Mongo metrics]

Finally, Apply a splitting over the Command Name:

[image: Splitting commands]

Now you should be able to see the detail on each command and which commands are generating those requests. Keep in mind that not always Commands = RU consumption, there are some commands that do not yield consumed RUs (you can see the consumed RUs of a command with [`GetLastRequestStatistics`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/set-throughput#GetLastRequestStatistics).

Comment: Thank you very much! Though this does not explain why this happens, it does help me dig into what is happening. I was suspecting that I had a bug somewhere, (and that might still be the case), but now I know where to start.

Again, thank you!